# Connect MySql (CPanel) remotely via JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, cpanel

=================**Code**===================

```
package com.name.file;

import java.sql.*;

public class JDBC {

// JDBC driver name and database URL
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://162.219.26.220:3306/waseianc_db";
// Database credentials
static final String USER = "waseianc_vinit";
static final String PASS = "pass";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {

        // STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        // STEP 3: Open a connection
        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        // STEP 4: Execute a query
        System.out.println("Creating statement...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql;
        sql = "SELECT id, first, last, age FROM Employees";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        // STEP 5: Extract data from result set
        while (rs.next()) {
            // Retrieve by column name
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            int age = rs.getInt("age");
            String first = rs.getString("first");
            String last = rs.getString("last");

            // Display values
            System.out.print("ID: " + id);
            System.out.print(", Age: " + age);
            System.out.print(", First: " + first);
            System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
        }
        // STEP 6: Clean-up environment
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        // Handle errors for JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

======================**Errors**========================

```
Connecting to database...
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link       failure

Last packet sent to the server was 2 ms ago.

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2104)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:729)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
at    com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:283)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.name.file.JDBC.main(JDBC.java:24)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at    com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:276)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2027)
... 12 more
```

=============================== **Cpanel Remote Access** ====================

[image]

=========================== **Cpanel MySQL DataBase** =========================

[image]

Comment: sounds more like a connection issue; db server may block connections from outside (either by whitelisting ip/network or by firewall)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Please contact your hosting provider and ask them to enable mysql port 3306 in firewall and try to login again.